# Does primary key datatype affect performance? SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a performance hit if you use one data type for your primary key versus another?

I have a large database that will be queried often, but only written to once a year. Will it matter at all if I supply an incremental primary key (integer) or let SQL Server give it a GUID?

Comment: The hit is really about the **clustering key** (not the primary key). The clustering key is replicated into every single non-clustered index on the table. So if you have a few NC indices on your table, then yes - the size and properties of the clustering key may have a **huge** impact on your perf. Read all about at [Kimberly Tripp's excellent blog](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/KIMBERLY/category/Clustering-Key.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a performance hit, in particular with large amounts of data.

In general, use the *smallest* data type that will fit your needs (you can always use a larger one if needed).

When it comes to  `INT(4)` versus `UNIQUIDENTIFIER`, the former is *much* smaller, takes less disk space and less bytes go over the wire. This also means that indexes using such a PK will be smaller. Of course, all of this data also needs to fit in memory, so the more you can fit into memory, the better.

Comment: Kinda what I figured.  What about using text as a primary key?  Like a three letter text code.  Should that too just be an int instead of the text?  Will accept answer when it lets me, thanks.

Comment: @DarrinCecil - If you _know_ that it will be enough, `CHAR(3)` or `NCHAR(3)` may be a better choice.

Comment: Among nchar(3) vs int for a primary key is what I meant.  Sorry.  This database will be pretty large, around 5 gig (couple tables with around a million rows).